# how exactly the word "alike" is functioning in this text?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The headline is:

"The Points Guy discusses his new app and explains how his credit card guidance can help travelers and non-travelers alike."

is "alike" saying the guidance will help travelers as well as non-travelers OR is it telling travelers and non-travelers are similar somehow

Answer (score 1):

**alike**, adverb - to the same extent

OED:

> **3. a. In like manner, likewise; in the same way, without distinction. Frequently used to show that something applies equally to a number of specified subjects.**
>
> 1994   Globe & Mail (Toronto) 19 Feb. a2/6   *Gender differences are trivial, and therefore..men and women should be treated alike.*

Comment: In other words - yes, it means that it will help both of them.